# Word2Vec: change of parameter, same results

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to train Word2Vec models and I would like to create an embedding to average the results over different models. The problem is that I am not getting the results I expected.  In fact, even if I change the parameters I end up  I am getting odd results.

The corpus is developed in this way, where 'documents' is a list of tweets.

```
word_corpus = [[str(token).lower() +'_' + str(token.pos_) for token in nlp(sentence) if token.pos_ in ('NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADJ') and len(str(token))>1] for sentence in documents]
```

Here the two models:

```
# initialize model
w2v_model1 = Word2Vec(vector_size=100, # vector size 
                     window=3, # window for sampling
                     sample=0.01, # subsampling rate
                     epochs=10, # iterations
                     negative=10, # negative samples
                     min_count=11, # minimum threshold
                     workers=-1, # parallelize to all cores
                     hs=0 # no hierarchical softmax
)

# build the vocabulary
w2v_model1.build_vocab(corpus)

# train the model
w2v_model1.train(corpus, total_examples=w2v_model1.corpus_count, epochs=w2v_model1.epochs)


#####


w2v_model2 = Word2Vec(vector_size=100, # vector size 
                     window=7, # window for sampling
                     sample=0.01, # subsampling rate
                     epochs=120, # iterations
                     negative=3, # negative samples
                     min_count=100, # minimum threshold
                     workers=-1, # parallelize to all cores
                     hs=0 # no hierarchical softmax
)

# build the vocabulary
w2v_model2.build_vocab(corpus)

# train the model
w2v_model2.train(corpus, total_examples=w2v_model2.corpus_count, epochs=w2v_model2.epochs)
```

and to evaluate them i am using the following syntax:

```
emb_df1 = (pd.DataFrame([w2v_model1.wv.get_vector(str(n)) for n in w2v_model1.wv.key_to_index],index = w2v_model1.wv.key_to_index)).T
emb_df2 = (pd.DataFrame([w2v_model2.wv.get_vector(str(n)) for n in w2v_model2.wv.key_to_index],index = w2v_model2.wv.key_to_index)).T
```

And I get this results.
[image: Results from the two different Word2Vec]

As you can see the number of words gets different but what seems odd to me is that, for words that are analyzed in both models, I get exactly the same coordinates and I can't understand why. If i well understood its working mechanism the results are provided after some randomization steps and so it should be basically impossible to get the same results everytime, so I am not able to understand to what could be due this error.

Comment: Have you examined your `corpus` to ensure it's of the size, and contents you expect? (What's `len(corpus)` & `corpus[0]`?) Have you enabled logging to at least the `INFO` level, & watched the logging output for confirmation that the expected steps, with somewhat varying treatments, are being applied?

Comment: `len(corpus) = 100000`
`corpus[0] = 'prices_NOUN' `.
I set `logging` option as `logging.basicConfig(filename = 'Test.log',level = logging.INFO)` and applied it to 
`logging.debug(w2v_model1.train(corpus, total_examples=w2v_model1.corpus_count, epochs=w2v_model1.epochs))`.
Looking better at its output : it collects 46164 out of 2412867 words and returns 
100(EPOCH) times 
`INFO EPOCH - 1 : training on 0 raw words (0 effective words) took 0.0s, 0 effective words/s
WARNING:EPOCH - 1 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (100000)`
To what could be due?

Comment: It's much easier to review code & output if you edit your answer to add it, with formatting, than squeeze into these unformattable comments. But I already see several potential issues: (1) above, your corpus is `word_corpus`, but here, it's `corpus` – if `corpus` is the real one, exactly how is it prepared? (2) if `corpus[0]` is just a string, it's the wrong format: each item in the corpus should be a *list of string words* – a single word like `'prices_NOUN'` isn't a text. …

Comment: (3) if logs show zero training has happened, the corpus is likely broken. So any "results" you're seeing are just the model's unchanged random-initialization. To be sure you have a properly re-iterable corpus, you can try running the line `print(sum(1 for _ in corpus))` multiple times in a row on the exact same `corpus` - if it always prints the same expected length, you know that at least `corpus` can be re-iterated over. If it ever prints `0`, you have some sort of error, such as using a single-use iterator (such as a generator) instead of a truly re-iterable Python sequence.